# Hibernate HQL autocompletion in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, hql

I've been trying for a while to configure HQL inspection/autocompletion in respect to my datasource. 
I tried some of the solutions offered here previously, but none worked for me. 
Is it even possible in the community version of IDEA?
If so, can anyone please write step-by-step guide to how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to File -> Project Structure -> Modules.
- Add a new Hibernate module.
- Right click on the desired module -> Add -> Hibernate.
- Select the newly created Hibernate configuration option, and click the (+) sign in the right pane to create hibernate.cfg.xml file.
- Go to File -> Project Structure -> Facets, and add new JPA.
- Select the newly created JPA configuration option, and click the (+) sign in the right pane to assign it your Hibernate configuration file.
- Open Persistence window, there you should see the list of your project modules.
- Expand the module name, and assign your data source to the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Now you can write queries on hibernate console and get HQL auto completion.

Answer (score 0):

As [IDE documentation says](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/jpa-and-hibernate.html) Hibernate support, including Hibernate console is available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition. Here is [full comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) between IDE editions (Hibernate is under Java EE technology category).